# wrong answer received after multiplying decimal with 1000

Tags: java, decimal

```
package test;

public class mulcheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double  output = (125000 / (1-0.035));
        double finout = output * 1000;
        System.out.println(finout);
    }

}
```

output
1.2953367875647669E8

expected output
12,95,33,678.7564766

after multiplying the value received in output variable with 1000 instead of moving the decimal to the right it is giving above output

tried using float....

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Answer (score 1):

Notice at the end `1.2953367875647669E8` its in exponential notation.

Use `BigDecimal`:

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class mulcheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double  output = (125000 / (1-0.035));
        double finout = output * 1000;
        // System.out.println(finout);
        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(finout);
        System.out.println(decimal);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
129533678.75647668540477752685546875
```

Better Approach use `printf` for formatting the `float` value:

```
package test;

public class mulcheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double  output = (125000 / (1-0.035));
        double finout = output * 1000;
        System.out.printf("%.7f", finout); // Returns  7 decimal places
    }

}
```

Output:

```
129533678.7564767
```